# Use CSS on database value - PHP framework

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, database

I need to use css styling's on MYSQL database value in HTML. I have a value of 'Y' for yes and 'N' for no in my vegetarian database row. I need to apply css to the 'Y' and 'N' values so I can style them with css? I'm using PHP to display my page.

```
if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo  '<h3 class="auto-title"> ' , $row["food"] , ' </h3>' , $row["description"] , '</br>  
        <div  class="vegetarian"> ' , $row["vegetarian"] , ' </div>
        <b class="auto-price"> ' , $row["price"] , ' </b><br> ';
    }
}
```

I've tried using this CSS below but no joy.

```
div.vegetarian [value="Y"] {
color: red;
}
```

Comment: `echo '<div class="vegetarian ', ($row['vegetarian'] == 'Y' ? 'vegetarian-y' : 'vegetarian-n'), '"> ...'`…?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using if condition easily

CSS:

```
vegetarian-y {
  color: red;
}

vegetarian-n {
   color: green;
}
```

php:

```
if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
        $class = "vegetarian-n";
        if($row["vegetarian"] == "Y") 
          $class = "vegetarian-y";
        echo  '<h3 class="auto-title"> ' , $row["food"] , ' </h3>' , $row["description"] , '</br>  
        <div  class="'.$class.'"> ' , $row["vegetarian"] , ' </div>
        <b class="auto-price"> ' , $row["price"] , ' </b><br> ';
    }
}
```

So what will happens,
it will check each and every time if vegetarian column value is Y then it will apply vegetarian-y class else it will apply vegetarian-n class